# How to apply a dynamic polymorphic function to a dynamic value?

Tags: haskell, dynamic, reflection

I would like to create a dynamic value out of the `Just` function to be able to apply it to `toDyn (1 :: Int)`.

My first difficulty is that I need to have a `Typeable` function. However this doesn't work:

```
createMaybe :: (Typeable a) => a -> Maybe a
createMaybe = Just

toDyn createMaybe
```

This fails to compile with `No instance for (Typeable a0) arising from a use of ‘toDyn’`

Is there a way to work around that?

Answer (score 1):

As [the docs for `Data.Dynamic`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html) says,

> A `Dynamic` may only represent a monomorphic value; an attempt to create a value of type `Dynamic` from a polymorphically-typed expression will result in an ambiguity error (see `toDyn`).

Perhaps you're looking for something like one of the following?

```
toDynJust :: Typeable a => a -> Dynamic
toDynJust = toDyn . Just
```

or the built-in [`fromDynamic :: Typeable a => Dynamic -> Maybe a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html#v:fromDynamic)?

Perhaps if you revealed more of what you're trying to do, rather than how you're trying to do it, one could better tell if that is the right approach. :-)

Comment: The context is the `registry` library which is using `Dynamic` under the hood: http://github.com/etorreborre/registry. It is possible to add monomorphic constructors to the Registry, for Hedgehog generators for example, but this means that I need one line for each `Gen (Maybe a)`  or `Gen [a]` that I want to include in the registry: https://github.com/etorreborre/registry/blob/e176f1337de9d17d16b83b35b973d94f965f408c/test/Test/Data/Registry/Internal/Gens.hs#L32